# How can I simplify this two lines of JavaScript so that it's not repetitive?

Tags: javascript

I managed to fix an issue by writing these two lines of code:

```
MyString = div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id');
MyString = MyString.replace('RemoveThis', '');
```

Although it's working fine, but it seems that I'm repeating MyString to often.
I tried to make it shorter as follow:

```
MyString = div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id').replace('RemoveThis', '');
```

But it didn't work.

Any hints how can I avoid repeating MyString?

Would the above solution pass a code review?

Comment: `div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id').replace` -> `(div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id')).replace`

Comment: You did the opposite of simplification. IMO the first approach is much simpler. Shorter isn't always simpler.

Comment: see [MDN HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) `div.dataset.type || div.dataset.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of repetition may actually be desirable as it makes the code easier to read and maintain.

But to do it your way, you're missing some surrounding brackets around `div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id')`

```
MyString = (div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id')).replace('RemoveThis', '');
```

Even better would be to format it a little better too...

```
MyString = (div.getAttribute('data-type') || div.getAttribute('data-id'))
             .replace('RemoveThis', '');
```

But I still prefer your original version!